# PDE-Based Triangle Inequality for Optimal Transportation

Tags: pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, measure-theory, optimal-transportation

Suppose $\Omega$ is a suitably regular domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\rho_0,\rho_1\in\textrm{Prob}(\Omega)$.  Benamou and Brenier showed that the $L_2$ transportation distance between $\rho_0$ and $\rho_1$ can be computed as follows:

$$d(\rho_0,\rho_1)^2=\inf_{\rho(x,t),v(x,t)}\int_{\Omega}\int_0^1\rho(x,t)|v(x,t)|^2\,dt\,dx$$

where $\rho(x,t)$ satisfies $\rho(x,0)=\rho_0(x)$, $\rho(x,1)=\rho_1(x)$, and $\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}+\nabla\cdot(\rho v)=0$.  This formula appears in many discretizations of optimal transportation.

We know $d(\cdot,\cdot)$ satisfies the triangle inequality because it was derived from the Wasserstein distance.  But, this evidence for the triangle inequality is "heavy" in that if you *define* Wasserstein distances using the above PDE formulation, you could only prove triangle inequality after showing a (complicated) relationship with the theory of optimal transportation.

**Is it possible to prove the triangle inequality directly from the "PDE-constrained optimization" formulation written above?**  Even an informal proof that ignores regularity issues etc. would be useful for me.

Thanks!

PS -- The Benamou/Brenier paper is "A computational ﬂuid mechanics solution
to the Monge-Kantorovich mass transfer problem," which lives here:  http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs002110050002

PPS -- Also posted here, but I realized it's probably not the right place:  https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/796634/edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I first wrote a longer answer, but it got somehow lost. Here is a rewritten shorter one. The idea is to simply construct a curve going from $\rho_0$ to $\rho_1$ to $\rho_2$. The only thing is to check how to make the reparametrization, i.e. decide the time $T$ when you move from the first transport to the other. This is how it should go:

Suppose $\rho_0,\rho_1,\rho_2\in\textrm{Prob}(\Omega)$ with $d_1 = d(\rho_0,\rho_1) >0$ and $d_2 = d(\rho_1,\rho_2) >0$. Let $T \in (0,1)$ so that
$\frac{1-T}{T} = \frac{d_1}{d_2}$ and let $(\rho^1,v^1)$ and $(\rho^2,v^2)$ be admissible pairs (i.e. having the correct marginals and satisfying the continuity equation) for defining the infimum in the distances $d_1$ and $d_2$. Let us assume that they even realize the infima. Now define an admissible pair $(\rho,v)$ for the distance from $\rho_0$ to $\rho_2$ as
$$
\rho(x,t) = \begin{cases}
\rho^1(x,t/T), & t \le T\\
\rho^2(x,(t-T)/(1-T)), & t > T\\
\end{cases}
$$
and
$$
v(x,t) = \begin{cases}
\frac1Tv^1(x,t/T), & t \le T\\
\frac1{1-T}v^2(x,(t-T)/(1-T)), & t > T.\\
\end{cases}
$$
Now 
$$
d(\rho_0,\rho_2)^2\le \int_{\Omega}\int_0^1\rho(x,t)|v(x,t)|^2\,dt\,dx = \frac1{T}d_1^2 + \frac1{1-T}d_2^2 = (d_1 + d_2)^2.
$$

Comment: Tricky!  Stupidly, I was fixing $T=\frac{1}{2}.$  Thanks -- this is very useful!